# Displaying HH:MM with SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, time, simpledateformat

I am having some problems when trying to format the time string I have created, I am trying to make it output only the time in HH:mm format by using the Date and Time conversion characters I found at this [website](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_date_time.htm)

```
DateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm R");
```

I get no problems without the "R" but then it outputs the entire date and time, defeating my goal.

Comment: What is R? Why you are using R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as `R` is [not documented to mean anything](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) but the documentation clearly says all other formatting characters *"...from 'A' to 'Z' and from 'a' to 'z' are reserved..."*, all bets are off about what you'll get if you use `R` in the formatting string.

Remove the `R`. If your goal is to have an `R` at the end of the string, append it to the result. If not, consult the documentation to see what formatting character you should be using.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "R" in the javadoc for SimpleDateFormat -- and it says that all unspecified letters are reserved.  I don't know where your website got it...

Answer (score 0):

According to the [date/time formatting symbols for `SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), there is no `"R"`.  In fact, I get an `IllegalArgumentException` trying to use the `"R"` as you have it.

You can't use `DateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm R");`.

However, [`printf` recognizes a different set of symbols](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) for formatting dates, and `"R"` is defined there:

```
'R'  Time formatted for the 24-hour clock as "%tH:%tM"
```

The website you refer to does mention `"R"` -- under the `printf` section, not for `SimpleDateFormat`.  It mentions to prepend `t` before all date/time format symbols.

Try

```
System.out.printf("%tR", new Date());
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need 'R'. If you want 24 hour "military" time, just use capital 'HH' and be done with it. Delete the R and you should get what you want. If you don't, you're probably doing something else wrong in your code that you haven't posted.